# Apache pig group by function is not giving expected output

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-pig, etl

I have data in `csv` format as shown below.

The data has the below format

```
"first_name","last_name","company_name","address","city","county","postal","phone1","phone2","email","web"
```

The sample data named under `User.csv`. The file contains below data.

```
"Aleshia","Tomkiewicz","Alan D Rosenburg Cpa Pc","14, Taylor St","St. Stephens Ward","Kent","CT2 7PP","01835-703597","01944-369967","atomkiewicz@hotmail.com","http://www.alandrosenburgcpapc.co.uk"
"Evan","Zigomalas","Cap Gemini America","5, Binney St","Abbey Ward","Buckinghamshire","HP11 2AX","01937-864715","01714-737668","evan.zigomalas@gmail.com","http://www.capgeminiamerica.co.uk"
"France","Andrade","Elliott, John W Esq","8 Moor Place","East Southbourne and Tuckton W","Bournemouth","BH6 3BE","01347-368222","01935-821636","france.andrade@hotmail.com","http://www.elliottjohnwesq.co.uk"
```

When I try the same to load using `PigStorage`

```
user = LOAD '/home/abhijit/Downloads/User.csv' USING PigStorage(',');

DUMP user;
```

The output of it is like :

```
("Aleshia","Tomkiewicz","Alan D Rosenburg Cpa Pc","14 Taylor St","St. Stephens Ward","Kent","CT2 7PP","01835-703597","01944-369967","atomkiewicz@hotmail.com","http://www.alandrosenburgcpapc.co.uk")
("Evan","Zigomalas","Cap Gemini America","5, Binney St","Abbey Ward","Buckinghamshire","HP11 2AX","01937-864715","01714-737668","evan.zigomalas@gmail.com","http://www.capgeminiamerica.co.uk")
("France","Andrade","Elliott, John W Esq","8 Moor Place","East Southbourne and Tuckton W","Bournemouth","BH6 3BE","01347-368222","01935-821636","france.andrade@hotmail.com","http://www.elliottjohnwesq.co.uk")
```

I want to do a group by on city. So I have written

```
grp = group user by $4; 
dump grp;
```

I get the output as :

```
( Binney St",{("Evan","Zigomalas","Cap Gemini America","5, Binney St","Abbey Ward","Buckinghamshire","HP11 2AX","01937-864715","01714-737668","evan.zigomalas@gmail.com","http://www.capgeminiamerica.co.uk")})
("8 Moor Place",{("France","Andrade","Elliott, John W Esq","8 Moor Place","East Southbourne and Tuckton W","Bournemouth","BH6 3BE","01347-368222","01935-821636","france.andrade@hotmail.com","http://www.elliottjohnwesq.co.uk")})
("St. Stephens Ward",{("Aleshia","Tomkiewicz","Alan D Rosenburg Cpa Pc","14 Taylor St","St. Stephens Ward","Kent","CT2 7PP","01835-703597","01944-369967","atomkiewicz@hotmail.com","http://www.alandrosenburgcpapc.co.uk")})
```

The company_name and address is creating a problem as it contains `','` as part of it. for example `"14, Taylor St"` in address or `"Elliott, John W Esq"` in company_name.

so my `$4` is treated for `"Taylor St"` and not the `"St. Stephens Ward"`

So because of the extra delimiter in the address data or the company_name data is not loaded properly or seperated properly and the group by fuction is not giving correct result.

How can I achieve the group by output as below

```
("Abbey Ward",{("Evan","Zigomalas","Cap Gemini America","5, Binney St","Abbey Ward","Buckinghamshire","HP11 2AX","01937-864715","01714-737668","evan.zigomalas@gmail.com","http://www.capgeminiamerica.co.uk")})
("St. Stephens Ward",{("Aleshia","Tomkiewicz","Alan D Rosenburg Cpa Pc","14, Taylor St","St. Stephens Ward","Kent","CT2 7PP","01835-703597","01944-369967","atomkiewicz@hotmail.com","http://www.alandrosenburgcpapc.co.uk")})
("East Southbourne and Tuckton W",{("France","Andrade","Elliott, John W Esq","8 Moor Place","East Southbourne and Tuckton W","Bournemouth","BH6 3BE","01347-368222","01935-821636","france.andrade@hotmail.com","http://www.elliottjohnwesq.co.uk")})


grp = group a by $5 ;
```

It won't be the solution for me. I already thought of it.

Comment: Try using CSVExcelStorage for loading your data. It should honor the escaping and properly load the data.

Comment: Will try and update you on the same

Comment: @LiMuBei: Thanks. Using 'CSVExcelStorage' worked for me. Now I am able to get the correct data after grouping...

Comment: Guess I'll create an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `PigStorage` does not take escaping into account, so creates columns for fields that should not be columns (each time an entry contains a comma).

Using `CSVExcelStorage` will solve this as this storage can deal with escaping, thus creating the right amount and sequence of columns.